# How to deal with forked gems and bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, rubygems, bundler

I've forked a gem and it is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/bgvo/mongoid-scroll).

Then, in Gemfile this is what I've got:

`gem 'mongoid-scroll', git: 'https://github.com/bgvo/mongoid-scroll.git'`

Whenever I make changes to the gem using Pry `gem-opem` command, changes are saved under the following directory:

`/Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/`

Some things confuse me:

1) In this directory there are two `mongoid-scroll` gems (`mongoid-scroll-7e23e72653c6` and `mongoid-scroll-23bc60ce76bd`) instead of just one. I thought that the gems inside this directory were the gems used when running bundler. How does bundler determine that this is the one to use an not the other one?

2) If I try to push changes to the Github repo:

```
Borjas-MacBook-Pro:mongoid-scroll-7e23e72653c6 borjagvo$ git push
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.00 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid-scroll-f814a84d6332ef5d28cf5db04da93b434e01f07b
   d8f9f91..696bdce  master -> master
```

I see that Github repo is not where changes are uploaded to.
Executing `git config --get remote.origin.url` to see origin:

```
Borjas-MacBook-Pro:mongoid-scroll-7e23e72653c6 borjagvo$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid-scroll-    f814a84d6332ef5d28cf5db04da93b434e01f07b
  Push  URL: /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid-scroll-    f814a84d6332ef5d28cf5db04da93b434e01f07b
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

What is a good way to upload changes to forked repo in Github from bundler used gem (remember that I'm using Pry command `gem-open`).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gemfile.lock should know what gem to load, when you do bundle update or installing a new gem, Gemfile.lock will be updated too with new gems, paths, etc.. and also the revision hash.

The hash at the end of the `Fetch/Push URL` that you see when you run `git remote show origin` must be the same as the `revision` from Gemfile.lock.

For example in my case with `active-admin` gem in Gemfile.lock I have:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
  revision: b7e8c7dde2c26a47e5db0dd1efc163405afadd9d
  specs:
    activeadmin (1.0.0.pre)
    ...
```

even if I have 2 active-admin gems, there is only one with revision: `b7e8c7dde2c26a47e5db0dd1efc163405afadd9d`

However, working with forks, this what I do:

I usually `fork` it, `pull` the froked `gem` on my computer, update the `Gemfile` of my app to use the gem from local-storage with `path` parameter, and I can update the gem without pushing it to github everytime I do a small change just to test it.

When I make it work as I needed, I push it to github and change the path in Gemfile of my app, run bundle again to update the path Gemfile.lock and I am all set. At least here you are not confused what gem the app is loading.

Comment: Thanks! So I should assume that you can specify to bundle a git repo to download the gem from. However, once it is on local-storage, you cannot make changes to it and push directly to the repo from which it was downloaded. Right?

Comment: If you clone the gem on your local storage, you'll have git set up by default so you can push directly to the repo it was cloned.. for example, you'll clone your forked repo and you can push to your repo only.

Comment: But, I am not sure I understood properly your question

Comment: Understood. My question was regarding to if bundle made that process you described automatically (now I know it doesn't). But it might make sense.